# Why won't this function work? Strlen, array for looping

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

This function checks for special characters by looping through an array of characters and checking if any of them don't match the list of allowed characters. What is wrong with this function? If you can help, thanks very much!

Assume that str_split_array($stringPassed); works perfectly (As i'm 99% sure it does, I use it in various other funcs)

```
    // returns true if a string has special characters
// $stringPassed = input string to split and check
// $checkWhiteSpace = check for whitespace, true or false
function hasSpecialCharacters($stringPassed, $checkWhiteSpace = true) {
    // Array of characters ALLOWED
    $allowedCharacters = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0);
    $arrayLen = strlen($stringPassed);
    $array = str_split_array($stringPassed);
    for($i=0;$i<$arrayLen;$i++) {
        if(!in_array($array[$i], $allowedCharacters)) {
            return true;
        } else if($checkWhiteSpace==true && $array[$i]==" ") {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You can easily validate $stringPassed against a regular expression to achieve the same?

Comment: `strlen` doesn't count characters, it counts bytes. So if your string is in unicode it won't give exact value. By the way, check what's the value of `$arrayLen`.

Comment: -1 What is your question? What result do you get and why is it different from what you want? "Why doesn't it work?" is only a real question if we are mindreaders.

Comment: That could be summed up in one line: `return (bool) preg_match('/[^a-z0-9'.(($checkWhiteSpace) ? '' : ' ').']/', $stringPassed);`

Comment: There's a built-in function to replace your hand-written `str_split_array` - it's known as `str_split`. But it's not necessary anyway, strings may also be accessed by index (for example: `$stringPassed[$i]`. But, as others have pointed out, you should probably be using a regular expression anyway.

Answer (score 6):

A better solution is Regex.

`return (bool) preg_match("/[^0-9a-z".($allowWhiteSpace ? " ":"")."]/i", $stringPassed);`

The `i` makes it case **insensitive**.

More on [Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

I also changed `$checkWhiteSpace` to `$allowWhiteSpace` to remove ambiguity.

Comment: If you are going to do that, you might as well just do `'/[\W_'.($checkWhiteSpace ? '' : ' ').']/'`

Comment: In order to mimic the OP's function you should return a boolean with a cast like `return (bool) preg_match ...`

Comment: Accepte your suggestions, thanks. Though, the `\W_` only makes 5 characters difference, and `1` or `0` will return `True` or `False` (but for `===`)

Comment: I know, I'm just being pedantic. +1 by the way. **EDIT** actually I've just realised that `\W` won't work because it will match a space regardless. Your original regex was better. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you :D (I am sometimes pedantic too) **EDIT** I will reverse the `\W`

Comment: My pleasure. Added thanks to @DaveRandom - also don't forget to accept answers, or the community will sometimes remind you of this. You get 2 rep for it too!

Answer (score 0):

scrap that function and use preg_match instead, it's much more efficient

```
function hasSpecialCharacters($stringPassed, $checkWhiteSpace = true)
{
    if($checkWhiteSpace)
    {
        $regex = "/^[a-z0-9 ]+$/" 
    }
    else
    {
        $regex = "/^[a-z0-9]+$/"
    }
    if(preg_match($regex, $stringPassed)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's a [regex cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v1/png/) that you should get familiar with.